# ¿Por qué char, hex, muestra ffffff?

Tags: c++

Tengo un *char []*, con el nombre de *buffer*, los datos son almacenados usando un ifstream en modo `binary mode`,

```
void File::mostrarBuffer(){
  for (int a = 0; a < std::strlen(buffer); a++){
    std::cout << std::hex << ((int)buffer[a]) << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout <<  "==="  << std::endl;

  for (int a = 0; a < std::strlen(buffer); a++){
    std::cout <<  buffer[a] << std::endl;
  }

  char charTest = '\211';

  std::cout <<  "==="  << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::hex << (int)charTest  << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::hex << (int)buffer[0] << std::endl;
}
```

El shell muetra lo siguiente:

```
ffffff89
50
4e
47
===
\211
P
N
G
===
ffffff89
ffffff89
```

Parte de fichero en hexdump ("`little-endian`"):

```
0000000 5089 474e 0a0d 0a1a 0000 0d00 4849 5244
```

¿Por qué imprime `ffffff89` y no `89`, y solo en el primer elemento del `char []`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Jonathan Wood https://stackoverflow.com/users/522663/jonathan-wood
>
> Porque su char es signed, trate de hacer casting hacia unsigned.

**esta forma trabaja para mi:**

```
 std::cout << std::hex << ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[a]) 
           << std::endl;
```

Comment: Si Jonathan Wood me mostro el camino, debajo puedes ver la forma que emplee desde su recomendacion Saludos